# UISearchBar delay display on NavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I used UISearchBar display on UINavigationBar by setting titleView of UINavigationBar at ViewDidLoad.

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
searchBar.delegate = self;
searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
searchBar.backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];

self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBar;
```

It works, but I had a problem. When I push into NavigationController, UISearchBar delay display until view did appear. I think it seem have to animated when set into titleView. What was problem?

Comment: Why don't you add search bar from storyboard?

Comment: I can't drap UISearchBar into NavigationBar in Storyboard

Comment: I resolved proble, just add frame for UISearchBar, searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600.0f, 44.0f)